# function myfuction() conflict with jquery

Tags: jquery, conflict

i have thumbnail image, when mouseover on thumbnail will be show in big size...

below this code:

```
<img onMouseOver="seebig('<{$pic}>')" style="cursor:pointer" src="path/images/<{$pic}>.jpg" border=0 width="45" height="40">
```

and function call like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">function seebig(id){ $('imgmove').innerHTML='<a href="path/images/'+id+'.jpg" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="path/images/'+id+'.jpg" width=280 ></a>';}</script>
```

BTW when i put jquery-1.3.2.min.js and prototype.js on heading this function not work? anyone can help...thank you

**SOLUTION**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
function seebig(id)
{ 
    var mv = document.getElementsByClassName('imgmove')[0];
    mv.innerHTML = '<a href="path/images/'+id+'.jpg" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="path/images/'+id+'.jpg" width=280 ></a>';
}
```

Thank you for [dima_horror](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2114398/dima-horror) ,but your tips still not worked before inserting jQuery.noConflict();

and now goes fine!!! thank you

Comment: Why would you use a jQuery version that is three years old? Can you even find 1.3.2 these days?

Comment: `$('imgmove').innerHTML` is plain wrong...

Comment: Open js console and check here for any errors.

Comment: whether `imgmove` is the target element id? if so then try `$('#imgmove').html('<a href="path/images/' + id + '.jpg" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="path/images/' + id + '.jpg" width=280 ></a>')`

Comment: $('imgmove') is var to call big size image.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: That depends: It's somewhat reasonable if you're using PrototypeJS or MooTools, or anything else that uses `$` to look things up by their `id` and give you an (augmented) element.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes.... +1 for that...

Comment: yes I am also using prototype.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change `$('imgmove').innerHTML` to `$('imgmove').html()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function seebig(id)
    { 
        $('imgmove').html('<a href="path/images/'+id+'.jpg" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="path/images/'+id+'.jpg" width=280 ></a>');
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE 2**
Try update html without jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function seebig(id)
    { 
        var mv = document.getElementsByClassName('imgmove')[0];
        mv.innerHTML = '<a href="path/images/'+id+'.jpg" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="path/images/'+id+'.jpg" width=280 ></a>';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `imgmove` is a tag name? May be class (`.imgmove`) or id (`#imgmove`) ? What errors in the console? _Why you downvote? I want to help you..._

Comment: I am also using prototype.js

Comment: still not worked....but after i'm insert jQuery.noConflict(); everything works fine.....thank you,

Answer (score 1):

From the code, it looks like the page in question is already using PrototypeJS or MooTools, both of which use the `$` symbol. jQuery *also* uses the `$` symbol, but if you need to make them co-exist, you can tell jQuery to release the `$` symbol using [its `noConflict` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict), like this:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

Then in any code where you need to use jQuery, not your previous library, actually use the symbol `jQuery`, which is a synonym for jQuery's `$`.

---

Why I think you're using PrototypeJS/MooTools: Because of the code `$("imgmove").innerHTML = ...;` assumes that `$` looks things up by their `id`, and that it returns a single (augmented) element. Both of those libraries do that.